# How to avoid "code smell" when using @NamedEntityGraphs annotation?

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa, annotations, entitygraph

In IntellyJ Idea I have installed SonarLint.

Code analizer says that I have to remove the "NamedEntityGraphs" wrapper from this annotation group.
Here is my code:

```
@NamedEntityGraphs({
        @NamedEntityGraph(
                name = Application.ONLY_NAME,
                attributeNodes = {
                        @NamedAttributeNode("foo"),
                        @NamedAttributeNode("bar")
                }
        ),
        @NamedEntityGraph(name = Application.FULL,
                attributeNodes = {
                        @NamedAttributeNode("foo"),
                        @NamedAttributeNode("bar"),
                        @NamedAttributeNode("buzz")
                }
        )
})
public class SomeClass {  ...  }
```

Here are the arguments from SonarLint:

> Annotation repetitions should not be wrapped
> Code smell, Minor, java:S1710
>
> Before Java 8 if you needed to use multiple instances of the same annotation, they had to be wrapped in a container annotation. With Java 8, that's no longer necessary, allowing for cleaner, more readable code.
> Note that this rule is automatically disabled when the project's sonar.java.source is lower than 8.
>
> Noncompliant Code Example

```
@SomeAnnotations({ // Noncompliant
        @SomeAnnotation(..a..)
        @SomeAnnotation(..b..)
        @SomeAnnotation(..c..)
})
public class SomeClass {  ...  }
```

> Compliant Solution

```
@SomeAnnotation(..a..)
@SomeAnnotation(..b..)
@SomeAnnotation(..c..)
public class SomeClass {  ...  }
```

**QUESTION:**

Does enybody know how to organize @NamedEntityGraphs in order to get complient code?

Comment: Why not just remove `@NamedEntityGraphs` since, as noted by your tool, it's unnecessary? The `@NamedEntityGraph` annotation is `@Repeatable`.

Answer (score 2):

Just do as the tool told you (and also @Slaw in the comments): Remove the outer annotation and just repeat [`@NamedEntityGraph` which is ok since it is `@Repeatable` with JPA 2.2](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.2/api/javax/persistence/NamedEntityGraph.html)

```
@NamedEntityGraph(
        name = Application.ONLY_NAME,
        attributeNodes = {
                @NamedAttributeNode("foo"),
                @NamedAttributeNode("bar")
        }
),
@NamedEntityGraph(name = Application.FULL,
        attributeNodes = {
                 @NamedAttributeNode("foo"),
                 @NamedAttributeNode("bar"),
                 @NamedAttributeNode("buzz")
       }
)
public class SomeClass {  ...  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have given your answer in your code itself.
Just remove `@NamedEntityGraphs`

```
@NamedEntityGraph(name = Application.ONLY_NAME,
                attributeNodes = {
                        @NamedAttributeNode("foo"),
                        @NamedAttributeNode("bar")
                }
        )
@NamedEntityGraph(name = Application.FULL,
                attributeNodes = {
                        @NamedAttributeNode("foo"),
                        @NamedAttributeNode("bar"),
                        @NamedAttributeNode("buzz")
                }
        )
public class SomeClass {  ...  }
```